# Android not logging app crash exceptions

Tags: android, logging

In my limited experience on a handful of Android devices, if an app crashes with an unhandled exception then that exception's written to the log. However I've come across a Samsung i8160 that doesn't. Other i8160s with various ROMs do. In fact, from boot, it doesn't log anything. It originated on eBay so the history is unclear, but rather than assuming it's an odd ROM and flashing something else I figured it was worth persisting in case the problem arises again elsewhere.

In researching, the first thing to try was to 'dial' `*#*#2846579#*#*` but this isn't recognised- it just tries to really dial that. There's a shorter `*#9900#` that does pop up a menu, but that only lets me dump the log and other info to files in /data/log for export. Since logging isn't up from boot, that doesn't export much.

Initially, /dev/log doesn't exist. One suggestion to fix this was to try `logcat-enable` from a shell. This isn't found. Another suggestion was to manually load the logging module by running `insmod /lib/modules/logger.ko` from a rooted shell. This brings logging up, but when an app crashes, all logcat outputs is

```
I/dumpstate( 8074): begin
I/dumpstate( 8074): done
```

I've found the dumpstate files, which include the logcat output, but there also it just notes creation of the dumps, not the exception that caused it.

As well as starting the module, I'm assuming somewhere there's some configuration determining what actions to take when an app crashes, and here it's not set to dump the exception and stack trace to the log because whoever did it figured logging wouldn't be running anyway. But I can't find anything like this. Does anyone have any ideas on how to progress further?

Answer (score 0):

Some apps have a "report" function inbuilt in case their app crashes. When you choose report on the ANR message, usually a log is created for sending it to the developer. Maybe you can get an app to crash and catch that log (or maybe make your own one)

Comment: I suspect the ANR's report button is just producing the dumpstate files I mentioned, with the same limitations (if it's not being logged, it's not there for dumpstate.) In this case it's my own app crashing with an unhandled exception in early startup. I've run it on a different device and I've got the log entry from that and it's shown what's (suddenly) going wrong, but it'd still be useful to get all the devices logging. Yes, I can (and elsewhere do) use a seperate logfile and rotate it but that's a somewhat inelegant way to do it, and doesn't catch problems in early startup.